# Parse error Firebase Real Time DataBase React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I only get this output when I do doc console.log. :{"date": "2022-04-12T19:17:14.413Z", "firstPlayer": true, "gameBoard": ["null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null", "null"], "roomid": "w273S", "secondPlayer": false} but when i can try console.log(doc.roomid) or anythink undefined error. How Can I parse this?

```
    function getRoomData(room){
    database()
    .ref(`rooms/${room}`)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc)
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRoomData(room){
    database()
    .ref(`rooms/${room}`)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data.roomid);
    })
}
```

Try this way

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: dont working :( console.log(data.roomid): undefinded